# ЭЦП. Алгоритмы подписания сообщений в блокчейне

Tags: bitcoin, блокчейн

В биткоине используется ECDSA алгоритм подписания сообщения. Так же я обнаружил некоторый алгоритм подписания, где приватный ключ представляется 256-ью парами секретных значений, и в зависимости от того, какой бит в хэше сообщения, то значение из пары секретных значений используется в подписи. Это означает, что это просто два разных алгоритма подписания или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: Не до конца раскрыт вопрос, где Вы обнаружили второй алгоритм? Заранее скажу что скорее всего Вы перепутали его предназначение, в блокчейн используется целый каскад алгоритмов. Подозреваю что второй ключ это как раз ключ подписи самого майнера, который подбирает значение под хеш

Comment: @artemgh Есть одноразовая подпись, где 256 различных пар секретных значений => такая подпись может использоваться только один раз, поэтому создается очень много одноразовых ключей приватых, а из них публичных, которые объединяются посредством использования merkle tree, где корнем является мастер публичный ключ. Так же есть алгоритм подписания эллиптической кривой, где на вход всегда подается один и тот же сгенерированный при создании кошелька секретный ключ (вроде так). Поэтому вопрос, и то и другое - просто разные алгоритмы подписания? (например в проекте X - ECDSA, в Y - одноразовая подпись)

Comment: Возможно это Вам поможет: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C

Comment: @artemgh, а можете еще подсказать, для каждой новой подписи в мультиподписи например группа подписантов выбирается рандомно? То есть, произошла транзакция, нужна подпись, юзается мультиподпись и группа подписантов выбирается рандомно на одну подпись или каким-то образом людей объединяют и они постоянно подписывают?

Comment: На этот вопрос точно не отвечу, но предположу что тут замешаны люди из блока, а уже там они подбираются в основном по комиссии, чем она выше, тем выше приоритет их обработки. Но это не проверенная информация)